# How to get RabbitMQ metrics for horizontal pod autoscaling?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I'm running GKE  Kubernetes cluster v11.3 and trying to use RabbitMQ metrics for HPA.
I do see RabbitMQ metrics:

```
 kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq| grep rabbit
      "name": "*/agent.googleapis.com|rabbitmq|num_messages",
```

But cannot use them in HorizontalPodAutoscaler:

```
ScalingActive  False   FailedGetPodsMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metric rabbitmq|num_messages: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: the server could not find the descriptor for metric rabbitmq/num_messages: googleapi: Error 404: Could not find descriptor for metric 'rabbitmq/num_messages'., notFound
```

Metric configuration:

```
metrics:
  - type: External
    external:
      metricName: custom.googleapis.com|rabbitmq|num_messages
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: In reference to your HPA error, it cannot get metrics from provided path.
Could you check output of `kubectl api-versions` to verify if there is /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 on the list?
YAMLs would be helpful. 
Have you included resources requests in the PODs configuration?

Comment: Please see below:  

     kubectl api-versions|grep custom . 
     custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1

Comment: >Have you included resources requests in the PODs configuration? 
I'm not sure I understand your question. AFAIK, external metric shouldn't be part of the pod.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue. Unfortunately without more information I am not able to do it.
Please provide additional data like configmaps, rabbitmq config, deployments